# Accessing the first business day of a Month

Tags: r, date, time-series

I need to know the first business day of a given month, is there some package in R containing a relevant function?

Comment: What do you mean by bussiness day? Which calendar?

Comment: Say for example UK calendar...

Comment: Don't say that for example if all you want is the first Monday of each month!

Comment: @JoshO'Brien I think he meant that he wants first day of the month that isn't on weekend. Luckily my english is as poor as the question's :)

Comment: @LorenzoRigamonti can you edit your question please and precise what do you mean by busniess day..I think you mean Open day. AT least according to the accepted answer..

Comment: @Hemmo -- Yeah, thanks, I don't know what I was thinking with that comment either. "Weekday" is the word I was after ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The **timeDate** package has a function `isBizday` that will help you here. There will be more elegant ways to convert the `dateTime` object to other formats, but this should at least get you started.

```
library(timeDate)

## Example data
dates <- as.Date("2013-01-01") + 0:364
Dates <- as.timeDate(dates)

## Extract the first business day of each month
bizDates <- dates[isBizday(Dates, holidays=holidayLONDON())]
firsts <- tapply(bizDates, months(bizDates), min)
sapply(firsts, function(X) as.character(as.Date(X)))
#            1            2            3            4            5            6 
# "2013-01-02" "2013-02-01" "2013-03-01" "2013-04-01" "2013-05-01" "2013-06-03" 
#            7            8            9           10           11           12 
# "2013-07-01" "2013-08-01" "2013-09-03" "2013-10-01" "2013-11-01" "2013-12-02"
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you want first day of the month that isn't Saturday or Sunday:

```
businessDay<-function(month,year){
  #3 first dates of the month is sufficient
  d <- as.POSIXlt(paste(year,month,1:3,sep="-")) 
  #POSIXlt object contains the info about the weekday as number 0-6 (starting Sunday)
  d[which(d$wday>0 & d$wday<6)[1]]
}

businessDay(3,2013)
[1] "2013-03-01"
```

Or if you want the name of the day:

```
businessDay<-function(month,year){
  d <- as.POSIXlt(paste(year,month,1:3,sep="-"))
  weekdays(d[which(d$wday>0 & d$wday<6)[1]])
}

businessDay(1,2013)
[1] "friday"
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `isBusinessDay`  from `RQuantLib` , which check if a day is a busniess day given a calendar. One idea is to give the first days of the month and take the min busniess day

For example here the first business day of April 2009 is :

```
library(RQuantLib)
dates <- seq(from=as.Date("2009-04-01"), to=as.Date("2009-04-05"), by=1)
min(dates[isBusinessDay("UnitedKingdom", dates)])
"2009-04-01"
```